# WARNING: LoadLibrary failed for srclient.dll with hr:8007007e

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

I have the following error message on my windows 2003 server x86:

WARNING: LoadLibrary failed for srclient.dll with hr:8007007e

in the windowsupdate.log while I am trying to install the WSUS sp2.
I tryed both with windows update and with a manual install.
Also I tryed to run: **msiexec /unregister** and **msiexec /regserver** without succeed.
Any advice ?